# How to show the result of local variables using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank guys who took interest in this question. All solved by the answer below. Sorry to make you confused by the non-clear question. English is not my mother tongue, so sometimes it is hard to explain in detail. Thank you all of you guys.

I just want to print out results and it doesn't seem right to printout 4 variables in a table. How can I solve this?

I tried to use print @local variable, but I think it works normally with transaction. Thank you

I am using Microsoft SQL Server; value would be city name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFindAverageValue6 
     @Value VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @AverageWinSpeed FLOAT
    DECLARE @AverageRainfall FLOAT
    DECLARE @MaximumTemperature FLOAT
    DECLARE @Minimumtemperature FLOAT

    IF @VALUE IN (SELECT station FROM weather GROUP BY station)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AverageWinSpeed = (SELECT AVG(ISNULL(WindSpeed, 0)) 
                                   FROM WEATHER 
                                   WHERE Station = @Value)
        SELECT @AverageRainfall = (SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Rain, 0)) 
                                   FROM WEATHER 
                                   WHERE Station = @Value)
        SELECT @MaximumTemperature = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Tmax, 0)) 
                                      FROM WEATHER 
                                      WHERE Station = @Value)
        SELECT @Minimumtemperature = (SELECT MIN(ISNULL(Tmin, 0)) 
                                      FROM WEATHER 
                                      WHERE Station = @Value)
    END
END
```

Execution:

```
spFindAverageValue4 @VALUE = 'AUCKLAND'
```

Comment: what is your issue with `print @AverageWinSpeed` ?

Comment: Not clear - do you want to **return** those values to the caller, or do you want to just print them out inside your stored procedure??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to do - but assuming you want to **return** those four values to the caller (so that the caller can then print them out), you could **vastly simplify** your stored procedure to something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFindAverageValue6 
     @Value VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        AVG(ISNULL(WindSpeed, 0)) AS 'AverageWindSpeed',
        AVG(ISNULL(Rain, 0)) AS 'AverageRainfall',
        MAX(ISNULL(Tmax, 0)) AS 'MaximumTemperature',
        MIN(ISNULL(Tmin, 0)) AS 'Minimumtemperature'
    FROM 
        dbo.WEATHER 
    WHERE 
        Station = @Value
END
```

and then call it like this:

```
spFindAverageValue4 @VALUE = 'AUCKLAND'
```

and you'd get back a result set of one row with four columns corresponding to each of the values you're selecting inside the procedure from the `dbo.WEATHER` table (those values of course are just totally made up - just to illustrate what to expect):

```
AverageWindSpeed    AverageRainfall    MaximumTemperature    MinimumTemperature
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     23.76               106.91              31.07                 -5.95
```

Comment: Thank you for your time devoted and excellent explanation. Seeing through your code, I could easily understand.!! Thank you so much again.

Comment: @JayceLila: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.